# Creating Entity Model with Cross Referencing Table - EntityFramework 4.1

Tags: entity-framework, navigation-properties, entity-model

Here is my scenario (tables):

```
Departments
====================
Id (int)
Name (varchar)

Employees
====================
Id (int)
Name (varchar)

EmployeesDepartmentXREFs
====================
EmployeeId (int)
DepartmentId (int)
```

When I import these 3 tables into EDMX model, I get 2 entities: Employee and Department. Entity Employee has navigational property Departments and entity Department has navigational property Employees.

And this is all fine. I actually like it this way.

But, problem starts when I want to add more fields in the XREF table, for example, I would like to have DateCreated, UserId fields to record when change is made and by who. If I add these two fields in XREF table, then my EDMX model will show 3 entities instead of two. It is not big issue, but since I am already done with coding, I am sort of looking for easy solution (to avoid coding).

Question: **Is it possible to add new fields into XREF (cross reference) table and to keep only two entities?** If yes, how would I update my datetime and userid information?

I assume that XREF entity has to be present in order to be able to update it (with date and user id), but I really like having navigational properties: **Departments** and **Employees**, versus having navigational properties **EmployeesDepartmentXREFs**.

Is there a middle ground for this? What is the best practice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if this will work for model first, but you could use the [NotMappedAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.notmappedattribute%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). I am especially not sure if this will fix the third entity from showing up, but it is definitely a path to look down.

**UPDATE**

After looking around, I found [this MSDN forum question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/db6df279-a925-443c-a616-7375867409a6/), which sounds like it is before code-first (which I do believe allows more than two columns in the mapping table via the fluent API) and fits your problem.

You could try the fluent API, but again, I am not sure if this will fix anything for model-first.  [Here is a good stack overflow question that shows how to use the fluent api to map the columns together.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028375/entity-framework-code-first-many-to-many-setup-for-existing-tables)

Last, [Here is a good article on your problem.](http://learnentityframework.com/LearnEntityFramework/tutorials/many-to-many-relationships-in-the-entity-data-model/)

Hopefully, this helps/clarifies things for you.

Comment: It seems that what I want is not possible. Your post got me reading about Fluent API which I didn't even know existed. :-). I'll look more into that.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a readonly helper property:

```
public class Department
{
    //...
    public ICollection<EmployeesDepartment> EmployeesDepartments { get; set }

    // because here is only a getter the property is ignored for mapping to DB
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees
    {
        get { return EmployeesDepartments.Select(ed => ed.Employee); }
    }
}
```

But this requires that you either have already loaded the `EmployeesDepartments` including the `Employee` from the database or that you use lazy loading (mark navigation properties as `virtual`) and the context the department has been loaded in is not yet disposed. Also, this property is useless for adding or removing relationships between `Department` and `Employee`.

Anyway, it requires that you write custom code. There is no way to introduce a property with automatic getter and setter and specify a mapping which would somehow "skip" your intermediate entity. Your model just does not have a many-to-many relationship anymore when you add properties to the join table and best practice is to consider it as two one-to-many relationships.