# How to specify a schema for a many-to-many relationship table?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have a User-Role many-to-many relationship, specified by this excerpt from an `EntityTypeConfiguration<Role>` derived class that allows me to specifiy schemas for single tables, e.g:

```
[Schema(SchemaNames.ParkPay)]
class WeekDayConfig : EntityTypeConfigurationWithSchema<WeekDay>
{
    internal WeekDayConfig()
    {
        Ignore(t => t.IsDeleted);
        Property(p => p.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(20);
    }
}
```

Now, for `Role`, the configuration class contains this code, and the resultant table `UserRole` gets created under the 'dbo' schema, not my desired schema. This is that code:

```
[Schema(SchemaNames.ParkPay)]
internal class RoleConfig : EntityTypeConfigurationWithSchema<Role>
{
    public RoleConfig()
    {
        HasMany(t => t.Users)
            .WithMany(t => t.Roles)
            .Map(m =>
                     {
                         m.ToTable("UserRole");                            
                         m.MapLeftKey("RoleId");
                         m.MapRightKey("UserId");
                     });
    }
}
```

Is there anything I can do, except script a schema change during the seeding phase of initialization, to have table `UserRole` created under the 'parkpay' schema and not the 'dbo' schema?

Comment: Did you try this? Looks like an overload of `ToTable`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028375/entity-framework-code-first-many-to-many-setup-for-existing-tables

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't see why this wouldn't work:

```
public RoleConfig()
{
    HasMany(t => t.Users)
    .WithMany(t => t.Roles)
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.ToTable("UserRole","parkpay");                            
        m.MapLeftKey("RoleId");
        m.MapRightKey("UserId");
    });
}
```

Comment: Neither do I, and it does. Thanks, I missed that overload.

Comment: Is there a DataAnnotations way of doing this?