# EF many to many with junction entity database first

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, ef-database-first

I have a junction table with and idenity primary key columns to realize a many to many relationship. Visual Studio automatically detects it as a many to many relationship and the junction table is not an entity.

How can i realize it that also this table is generated as an entity? I need this for breeze.js .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6028375/1341477

Comment: Ooh, sorry I just reliased you actually want that entity... not sure you can stop the designer doing that by itself but you have two options I know of 1. Manually edit the edmx file 2. Add additional column e.g Id to the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add additional columns (or properties) to that table (or model).

You said that your table has acolumn named ID and it's the primary key withe `IsIdentity` set to true. It must works, I'm using this approach...

There must be a problem or missing with your table definition. However, if all are OK, just add a nullable column in your table and update your model from database. The problem will go away.